# Prevention of Data loss when switching from Primary to secondary database in Azure SQL during failover test

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

During the failover test in azure database from Primary to secondary. I see that everytime there is a loss of 3 seconds worth data during the switch. I want to minimise this data loss.

The azure documentation in the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-sql-db?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#preventing-the-loss-of-critical-data

states that "To protect critical transactions from data loss, an application developer can call the sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync stored procedure immediately after committing the transaction".

How can we achieve this point ?

Does this statement mean, we need to add a sql script which automatically get triggered during each commit ? Has anyone tried this option ?
Is there any other way to optimise the data loss ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a asynchronous replication so data loss is possible during failover. By specifying GracePeriodWithDataLossHours you make sure that if the outage is recoverable within the specified time, then you don’t failover over and therefore avoid the data loss.

Because verification of the scale of the outage and how quickly it can be mitigated involves human actions, the grace period cannot be set below one hour.

Comment: Will using sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync  sp have any impact ?

Comment: To prevent data loss synchronous replication should be in place and  is not supported on automatic failover groups. You can achieve something similar by running sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync after transactions that you wish to be durable. However, forced synchronization impacts performance because it blocks the calling thread until all committed transactions are replicated.